# PhoneGap FileTransfer Auth not sending

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am sending authorization with this code and it works perfectly

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: backendURL, dataType: 'html', async:true,     headers:{"Authorization": AUTH }, data: {
},success: function (data){

}});
```

This is the code that doesn't work

```
var uploadURL = data;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};

    options.headers={"Authorization": AUTH, "Connection": "close" };

    params.functionCall = 'genericImageUpload';
    params.eventId = currentEvent
    params.isVideo = '1';

    options.params = params;
    options.fileName  = 'tmp.jpg';//here
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    console.log( options );

    ft.upload(imageURI,
        uploadURL,
    function(result) {
        hideLoader();
        currentProblemImgUrl = result.response;
        $("#uploadImgReportBtn").html('Screenshot Uploaded!');
    },function(error) { 
        hideLoader();
    }, options);
```

the code on the php side says that $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] from the second code is empty but works for the first post call

This was working at one point but is no longer working.